# Cohomological criterion for being a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

The Theorem of Horrocks sais that a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ splits into a direct sum of line bundles if and only if all the intermediate cohomologies vanish, i.e. $H^i(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{F}(j))=0$ for all $0<i<n$ and all $j$.

Is this also true if $\mathcal{F}$ is not assumed to be a vector bundle but rather a coherent sheaf? So my question is: Is a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ whose intermediate cohomology groups vanish necessarily a vector bundle?

If yes, I would in particular be interested in a citable reference.

Comment: I don't know what theorem you are referencing, but locally free sheaves are vector bundles. Do you mean line bundles?

Comment: That's definitely what is meant. Horrocks' theorem is Theorem 2.3.1 in [Okonek-Schneider-Spindler](https://books.google.com/books?id=OG348syTqC8C).

Comment: It is trivial to show that if the above vanishing holds for a coherent sheaf, then it is indeed a vector bundle.

Comment: @Mohan If it is trivial, can you give me a hint?

Comment: @the others: yes, I have fixed the typo

Comment: If a non-zero coherent sheaf $F$ has support $X$ subset of projective space with $r=\dim X<n$, then $H^r(F(n))\neq 0$ for sufficiently negative $n$. By easy induction, your hypothesis implies thus $F$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay and thus a vector bundle.

Comment: What if $F$ is supported on a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Schemer said in the comments, if your sheaf $F$ is supported on a point then all intermediate cohomology vanishes, but it is not a vector bundle. However, this is practically the only problem that can occur.

Specifically, Hartshorne, in Lemma 6.3 Chapter 3 of *Ample Subvarieties of Algebraic Varieties*, gives the following result:

> Let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}^n_k$. Then there exist integers $m_i$ such that $E\cong\sum_{i}\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(m_i)$ if and only if
>
> i) $H^{0}(\mathbb{P},E(m))=0$ for all $m\ll 0$, and
>
> ii) $H^{i}(\mathbb{P},E(m))=0$ for all $m$ and $0<i<n$.

A related result is the following:

> If $X$ is a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field then a coherent sheaf $E$ is locally free if and only if $H^{i}(X,E(j))=0$ for all $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ and $j\ll 0$.

One direction is from Serre Duality.
The other direction is a proof by contradiction. Specifically, assume that $\mathscr{E}xt^{i}_{X}(E,\mathscr{O}_{X})\neq 0$ for some positive $i$.
Then Serre Duality and Beilinson's Spectral Sequence give you a contradiction.
Abe and Yoshinaga explicitly write the proof in Lemma 3.2 of *Splitting criterion for reflexive sheaves* (the arXiv version - not the published version!)